# R grid mismatch of units

Tags: r, r-grid

The following function draws the rectangle r1 as required, but an attempt to offsets it by 0.5 in native units fails. I have tried x=unit(1,"native"), etc. but this does not solve the trivial problem. Thank you for your help.

```
#rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library(grid)
vp__g = viewport(xscale=c(-1.5,5.5), yscale=c(-5.5,2.0))
pushViewport(vp__g)

test = function() {
   r1 = rectGrob(x=0, y=0, width=2, height=1, default.units="native")
   grid.draw(r1)
   r1a = editGrob(r1, vp=viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5), name="r1a") 
   grid.draw(r1a)
}
test()
```

Comment: `r1a = editGrob(r1, x=unit(0.5, "native"), y=unit(0.5, "native"), name="r1a") ` seems to work